# PARSING simple_html_dom results

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have the following code:

```
include('../scrape/simple_html_dom.php');
$file = "http://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2233";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($file);

foreach($html->find('table[class="leaderboard-table round-4"]') as $div){
    $Rd1 = $div->find('td[class="round2  in post"]');
}
```

I'm attempting to parse the data from that url and then insert by 'class=full-name" the Round1, Round2, Round3 and Round4 scores.

Hower, I keep getting an error that this is an array to string conversion. Can anyone offer guidance? I can't even isolate the data to insert it into a DB.

Comment: $Rd1 is an array here because `find` without a second argument returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your `simple_html_dom()` class does but just offhand, it's likely you have to first get the contents of the file and load that string since you don't have direct ownership of the file:

```
include('../scrape/simple_html_dom.php');
$file = "http://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=2233";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
# FETCH THE CONTENTS FIRST
$html = file_get_contents($file);
# THIS MAY BE LOADING A FILE, SO INSTEAD LOAD STRING
# PERHAPS THERE IS A load_string() METHOD?
$html->load_file($html);
/**Continue code...**/
```

If you need to load from a file, get the contents and temporarily store to a file using `file_put_contents($html,'temp.txt')`, then use the `load_file()` method...but it all depends what this class does.

Comment: Html_simple_dom is supposed to be a class similar to curl. My overall goal is to scrape the data by html class and insert that into a database. If there's an easier way, I'm open to it.

Comment: Well I'm not saying what you have is necessarily wrong, but generally, a function or method that is along the lines of `load_file()` or `load_from_file()`, etc. usually means the file is under your control (local). If it's remote, you may have to use a string load method. Does that class have a method to load from a string?